# A Mercurial update hook to send certain data to a text file

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-hook

I guess this is really 2 questions:

1. How do I get an update hook to execute the following:

`hg heads --template 'version {tags}\tbuild {rev}.{node|short}\tcommitted on {date|shortdate}'`

Simply putting: `update = <above command>` in the `[hooks]` section of the hgrc file, doesn't seem to work.

2. How do I redirect output from the above to a text file? Appending `> log.txt` or `| log.txt` doesn't work at all

I'm sure this is really basic and my command line knowledge is really basic - I just learned all of the above command this morning!

BTW, if it helps, I am running TortoiseHg 2.6.1 with Mercurial 2.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. According to [Hooks wiki-page](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Hook)

> Hooks can be implemented as either external programs, or internal python calls.

i,e you can't write `hg COMMAND` directly in [hooks] section, but can write yjis command in shell-script, which in called in hook. Something like

```
[hooks]
update = updatehook
```

with `updatehook.sh` | `updatehook.bat` in PATH (or with full path to script), in which you have as main part

```
hg heads --template "version {tags}\tbuild {rev}.{node|short}\tcommitted on {date|shortdate}\n" > SOMEPATH/log.txt
```

(note added `\n` at the end of template - for multi-head repository it's needed)

```
>hg heads --template "version {tags}\tbuild {rev}.{node|short}\tcommitted on {date|shortdate}\n"
version default/2.0 tip build 4638.4a48cef94e2e committed on 2014-12-24
version default/master  build 4620.de0053588acf committed on 2014-12-23
version default/1.6     build 2344.fc32e948fcba committed on 2013-01-06
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much! I did read about implementing hooks as external programs, but clearly didn't comprehend what it meant. I know, I'm slow. But your explanation was clear and concise and I now understand what's going on. Thanks again.